# PHP auto uploading images

Tags: php, image, upload, passwords

I really have no idea where to go right now, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I want to create a site (on a webpage), where people can upload images and videos (preferably only people with a username and password can upload). If the user could create a new page/folder to put the images in would also be preferable.

Right now I know how to create a site where I can upload an images to a folder on my computer, but I don't know how to get it to upload it to the site.

Any links, ideas or google searches you have will be helpful.

Comment: I would highly suggest looking at [blueimp](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Answer (score 0):

I love this jquery plugin http://www.dropzonejs.com/ . Its easy to use :)